# Install Firefox OS on Nexus 7 get error messages assert failed

Tags: android, macos, nexus-7, firefox-os

I installed Firefox OS (version 1.2) which was downloaded from XDA with ClockworkMod on my Nexus 7 , but i got error messages.

The error messages showed :

```
Installing update...
assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "flo" ||
               getprop("ro.build.product") == "flo" ||
               getprop("ro.product.device") == "deb" ||
               getprop("ro.build.product") == "deb"

E:Error in /sdcard/0/b2g_flo_1.2_20131011-2.zip
(Status 7)
```

And I checked the updater-script with Sublime Text 2 :

```
assert(getprop("ro.product.device") == "flo" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "flo" ||
       getprop("ro.product.device") == "deb" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "deb");

ui_print("FirefoxOS installer");
show_progress(1.00000, 10);

unmount("/system");
format("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system", "0", "/system");
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system", "/system");
```

So i removed the assert part and packed a new zip.
But i still couldn't install it without any error message.
And console showed :

```
Opening update package...
Installing update...
Installation aborted.
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem ?
That will be a great help !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. 

Comment: I was trying to update my Firefox OS device with from the sd card and it tells me that there is a  signature verification failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
This port is for the new 2013 nexus 7 which have 'flo' or 'deb' device names.
the old nexus 7 is "grouper" the old nexus 7 with GSM is "tilapia'

Comment: Yes, I also notice that ! Is there any port for 2012 nexus 7 ? And how do you build for 2012 nexus 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line:

```
format("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system",
       "0", "/system");
```

and format manual on CWM storage option before installing zip.